# How to return individual data properly in GraphQL

Tags: javascript, express, graphql

I am working graphql right now.
I am new to this graphql.

so right now, I am done making functionality to return all the `Note` and mutation.
meaning, I can add and get `Note` data.

And I was trying to make a function that returns one `Note` object according to given id.

here is my code

```
notes: async () => {
    try {
      const notesFetched = await Note.find();
      return notesFetched.map(note => {
        return {
          ...note._doc,
          _id: note.id,
          createdAt: new Date(note._doc.createdAt).toISOString(),
        }
      })
    } catch(error) {
      throw error
    }
  },

  note: async ({ id }) => {
    try {
      let note = await Note.find({ _id: id });
      
      // to make sure if there is a note object that is returned from db
      if(note.length > 0) {
        note = note[0]
      }
      
      return note;

    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  },

  createNote: async args => {
    try {
      const { author, user, content } = args.note;
      const note = new Note({
        author, 
        user,
        content
      })
      const newNote = await note.save();
      return { ...newNote._doc, _id: newNote.id }
    } catch(error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

this code works, but I feel not right about my note function.
i am checking if any data is returned, if yes, get first data in the returned array using `[0]`

please let me know if there is a better solution to this.

Thank you in advance.

```
type Query {
    users: [User!]
    notes: [Note!]
    note(id: ID): Note
  }
```

```
│   app.js
│
├───graphql
│   ├───resolvers
│   │       index.html
│   │
│   └───schema
│           index.html
│
└───models
        note.js
```

Comment: The signature of `note` in the `Query` states that it returns `Note` and not `[Note]` and so having to check for length in your `note` function does seem strange.  What does the underlying resolver for `note` of `Query` return?  I would start the investigation there.

Comment: it returns note object. since ```Note.find({ _id: id })``` returns array of Note object that matches with the given id, I used ```[0]```

Comment: What is the structure of `Note`?  What other API's does it expose and/or what underlying library is it relying on to get the data?